# Syntax error on Service Provider

Tags: laravel, syntax-error, service-provider

I don't understand why, but I can't get rid of "syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)" after setting a Service Provider. Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

My ServiceProvider:

```
namespace Repositories;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class MainPageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public function register()
  {
  $this->app::bind('MainPageInterface', 'MainPagesRepository');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$this->app->bind('MainPageInterface', 'MainPagesRepository');
```

or

```
\App::bind('MainPageInterface', 'MainPagesRepository');
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it worked. I got that syntax from an article I was following so probably the writer made this small mistake.